# SQL Delta dependency circular reference

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, delta

SQL delta tool shows warning for my SP. It says that there is a potential dependency circular reference. How to find out the issue ?

i used the following script to check the issues with tables :

```html
SELECT 
  OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(fk1.parent_object_id)
   + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(fk1.parent_object_id), 
  OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(fk2.parent_object_id)
   + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(fk2.parent_object_id)
FROM sys.foreign_keys AS fk1
INNER JOIN sys.foreign_keys AS fk2
ON fk1.parent_object_id = fk2.referenced_object_id
AND fk2.parent_object_id = fk1.referenced_object_id;
```

so far no result. It seems the issue with SP

Comment: I don't think your delta tool is talking about foreign keys. I would look at `sys.sql_expression_dependencies` perhaps, it's possible it's as simple as you created it like `CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.foo AS ....` and then you had an `EXEC dbo.foo` with no `GO` in between, meaning `EXEC dbo.foo` is now part of the body. What happens when you execute the stored procedure? Have you looked at it? The issue might be a lot more obvious than you think.

Comment: @RhythmWasaLurker there is some info in sys.sql_expression_dependencies. i don't understand how this info can help me ? i checked the SP , there is GO statement after CREATE PROCUDERE